# Is it somehow possible to merge the discussion/answers of a pair of duplicate questions together?

Tags: discussion, merged-questions

After some mistakes on my part, I noticed I made several duplicates of my own questions.  I would delete them, but some of the content in both instances was sometimes very helpful or applicable and I wish to preserve it.  Is there any way to merge some of the content, but not all the content (such as the duplicate tag, or duplicate indicator, that would be silly).  I notice that it is possible for the moderator to do this, but it would also be nice if the question that got picked to keep could be chosen by the asker if they asked both questions and didn't do an edit simply because the question was changed so much that the content of the question was different, just with the same meaning?

Comment: I don't really understand why you only want to merge some of the content.  If they are similar enough, just flag one as a duplicate of the other.  Otherwise, leave them as separate questions.

Comment: @Anonymous: You'd rather not have all the answers consolidated in one place?

Comment: @BoltClock I just thought it would be easier and quicker if the mods did not need to be bothered by it.  Wouldn't wanting all answers in one place qualify all (or at least most) duplicates for a merge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we can merge questions provided the questions themselves are exactly identical (which is usually the case with reposts). There is nothing stopping you from choosing which one of them you would like to keep — just make sure when flagging that you state very clearly which one of the links should be used as the merge destination.

Comment: What if they have already been flagged?

Comment: Also found that I couldn't flag the post that came before as the duplicate, even though the question that I asked afterward and was flagged as a duplicate by someone else is phrased better.